# Profile picture on election page not updated, but all other information is

Tags: discussion, bug, election, profile-picture

I have updated my profile photo in ProWebmasters and I noticed that it is not updated on the [ProWebmasters election page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/4) (2013 election). But other information like reputation count, member for last 2 years, moderation badges score, editing badges score and participation badges score were updated. Why is my profile picture alone not updated? Is it a bug, or is there any reason behind this?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe cache, when did you change the picture?

Comment: Yesterday night. Will it take more than 18 hours to cache?

Comment: Can't be 100% sure, some things are cached for 24 hours.

Comment: @ShadowWizard `Can't be 100% sure` means there is no official news about caching time? Am I right?

Comment: Yep, 100% right. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Now my profile photo has been updated after 24 hours as said by you :) :) Posted my answer too ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally my profile picture on election page has been updated after 24 hours as estimated by [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266106/profile-picture-on-election-page-not-updated-but-all-other-information-is?noredirect=1#comment863427_266106). ;-)

[image]

Comment: And now we know the avatars on election pages are cached for 24 hours. Cheers!